# How to prompt for username and password when acquiring an access token in Java

Tags: adal

When the following C# code is executed, the user is prompted (by an ADAL window) to enter a username and password.

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common", false);
AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken(serviceUrl, clientId, new Uri(redirectUrl));
```

I am converting the code to Java using ADAL for Java from GitHub. I do not see any acquireToken() method call that matches the one I used in C#. The code I am currently using is:

```
AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(
    "https://login.windows.net/common", false, service);
Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(RESOURCE_URL, CLIENT_ID, username, password, null);
AuthenticationResult result = future.get();
```

However, ADAL does not prompt for username/password. I have to add Java code to my console app to do that. Is there a better way? I would prefer to have the same experience as in the C# version.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there isn't support to pop up a ADAL window through Java.

Answer (score 0):

ADAL Java does not support a method to prompt user interaction today as the user interaction varies in Java applications based on the platform.

But it is possible to use ADAL Java [Auth code flow](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-with-authorization-codes) to acquire tokens in the context of a user in a web application. You will need to craft a request to first acquire the Authorization code from the /authorize endpoint of Azure AD. This allows the user to authenticate with their username and password on the Azure AD login page. You can then call the method `acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode` to get tokens for the user. Here is a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect) for this flow.

If you need user to authenticate at the Azure AD login prompt in a console application, you can also consider the [device code flow](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/wiki/Device-Code).